# Can a malware prompt the user to type the system password?

Tags: linux, macos, security, malware, trojan

On OS X, when I install new software, the system pops up a dialogue window and asks me to input administrator password.

Is it possible that some malware pops up a window which is exactly the same as the real one, except that it stores the password and send it somewhere?

// Update

The password of my local machine would be useful:

1, when a hacker has already got into my system, and need my password to execute priviledged commands;

2, when a hacker has already got my account name, and only need a password to hack into my account. Many people use a single password in a number of places and the local password is a good guess for the account's password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is.

why should it not be possible? it even sounds to hard to write such a behavior for a malware.

but actually i dont know why a malware want to send your the administration password from your local computer to someone.

//@update

yeah for sure u can use a password for some things, but if u are able to create a malware, which gets acces to a computer to sniff your passwort for the local account, you should be also able to do this stuff without having the password.

for sure, many malwares want to get passwords, but they normally try to get passwords for onlineaccounts or your banking account.

but at last the answer of your question still is: yes it is possible